# Catching flash POST from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a series of .swf files that I inherited from an old version of a site I'm trying to rebuild.

When flash_element.submitForm() is called, they POST some data directly to a static url ("/submit"), then depending on the response, reload the browser page.

I would very much like to capture the data that they POST using javascript - preferably without it getting sent at all - so that I can have more intelligent logic to handle to request/response than is built into the .swf files I've inherited.

Basically: When a flash object makes a http request, can I catch and cancel this event in Javascript?

Comment: @breton's answer is correct.  You are also neither working efficiently, nor maintainable, when using this kind of "hack" to get around quirks in legacy code.  If you're desperate to rebuild this site without source code - for whatever reason -  either mimic its behavior and re-program it, or use a decompiler like Trillix to get started.

Comment: I know, and I should never have taken this project. But now I have three options - 1) Back out, leaving me with 80 hours unpaid and them with a buggy/insecure website (their current one). 2) Spend 80+ *more* hours (unpaid) reworking 30+ flash files, all hardcoded in stupid ways, and overrun the deadline by a month. 3) Write some hacks, give them an unmaintainable-but-better-than-their-current-one site.

It's not *good*, but #3 is the best option I have at this point.

Comment: I know that situation, but my experience is that unless you really need the money, it's usually better to back out than to release a faulty product: You will put in far more hours working around the bugs and glitches, than you would redoing the whole thing. All the inherited troubles will be attributed to your work, and in the end you will pay dearly for being too soft on your customers. If there's a way to make them understand, you should try to move that deadline and do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no. You can try and use the various swf disassembler/reassembler things like the swfdump.exe that comes with flex to get rid of the post, or change it to a javascript call. There's precious little control or knowledge you can gain from a swf directly from javascript that the swf doesn't make explicitly available via the appropriate API's. This is is as it should be- if what you suggested were possible it would be a fairly serious security hole.